# How does a factory internally works in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, singleton, factory

I am going through this [blog](http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/).

[image]

The author puts forward,

When you’re using a ***Factory*** you create an ***object***, add properties to it, then ***return that same object***. When you pass this service into your controller, ***those properties on the object*** will now be available in that controller ***through your factory.***

So, as per my understanding, this line

[image]

gets replaced by

[image] [image][image]

as ***service***, the ***object*** being ***returned*** when we invoke ***myFactory()***.

No issues upto this point,

Now consider the snippet,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var module =  angular.module('MyApp', []);

    module.factory('VaderService', function() {
        var VaderClass = function(padawan) {
            this.name = padawan;
            this.speak = function () {
                return 'Join the dark side ' + this.name;
            }
        }
        return VaderClass;
    });

    module.controller('StarWarsController', function($scope, VaderService) {
        var luke = new VaderService('luke');
        $scope.luke = luke.speak();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp"> 
    <table ng-controller="StarWarsController">
        <tbody>
        <tr><td>{{luke}}</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

prints as,

```
Join the dark side luke
```

I failed to understand what happens here, with this line

```
var luke = new VaderService('luke');
```

We created an ***instance*** of the factory ***VaderService('luke')*** passing the string `luke` as a parameter, but surprisingly, no arguments are defined in

```
module.factory('VaderService', function() {...
```

Secondly, a ***function*** is returned i.e ***VaderClass()***, and not an ***object***. (I know very well that functions in javascript are first-class objects).

How does the string `luke` gets passed to the argument in ***VaderClass*** function?

Comment: But you return this one `var VaderClass = function(padawan)`, and this is what is being applied. External function there are used just as an enclosure.

Answer (score 2):

The lines are not replaced as you stated. Basically, as soon as you inject the factory the code inside it gets executed once. Angular will then execute the `VaderService` function once with new. The result (so return inside the factory) is the object that will be passed to each and every place where you inject the factory.

Please be aware that Angular terminology is in this realm a bit counter-intuitive compared to object-oriented languages. In Java, a factory is used to produce objects of a certain kind. In Angular this factory is used to create a single object that is shared among the module. This is more of a Singleton in traditional object-oriented speaking.

If what you want is a parametrized factory, then you should consider adding an additional init() function to your factory's return, that will change a local variable inside the factory. This closure can then be used to persist state across controllers or directives.

Comment: @Dameas: I have difficuly in understanding how the string 'luke' is passed to the argument in VaderClass function., even though the constructor function VaderService is invoked.(where there is no argument)

Comment: AngularJS internally calls the function once with new. The arguments of the factory function are empty, as they are used to inject dependencies.

Comment: Can you please extend a bit which fn AngularJs internally calls , which you referred to in your comment. Is it VaderService or VaderClass?

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari: Is it okay for you now?

Answer (score 0):

Just understand `VaderClass` is a constructor. The factory only creates another global `VaderService` constructor, which does the same.

```
var myfact = function(name, constructor_closure){
     window[name] = constructor_closure()
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that VaderClass is a constructor function and not just a normal fn.

Comment: @shirgill_ansari every js function can be used as constructor